# How can I use both "strict-dynamic" and "unsafe-inline"?

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

Although 'strict-dynamic' was used for use in 'chrome' and 'firefox', Safari did not support it, allowing named hosts and 'unsafe-inline' as fallback.

But Safari doesn't support 'unsafe-inline' with 'strict-dynamic'.

Although my csp policy is

`'nonce-${hash}' 'strict-dynamic' ...named hosts 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` ,

Safari says me

```
Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

Is it impossible using 'unsafe-inline' as fallback 'strict-dynamic' on Safari??

Other browsers work well. Even 'IE'.

Comment: It's not possible, because `'hash-value'` and `'nonce-value'` both cancels `'unsafe-inline'`.

Comment: @granty Thanks. I didn't know CSP Level2 Browser doesn't support pair, 'nonce, hash-value' and 'unsafe-inline'.

Comment: I have also not met such browsers, probably this is an archaism left over from a long time ago.

Comment: @granty I saw this reference. https://content-security-policy.com/strict-dynamic/. But I think I misunderstood because my english was short... :(
Anyway.. Thanks..!!

Comment: Be careful with the site`content-security-policy.com`, it contains a lot of misleading. At the page you referred  is written: *`'strict-dynamic'` will ignore `'unsafe-eval'`*, but it's **not true**.

Comment: OMG.... Thanks for advise...

Comment: In case someone else lands here out of confusion: the [CSP2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-script-src) specifically states the presence of a nonce/hash in script-src MUST cause 'unsafe-inline' to be ignored. The [CSP3 draft spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#strict-dynamic-usage) clarifies this also occurs with 'strict-dynamic'. The specification does not allow mixing hashes/nonces with unhashed/unnonced inline code in any version.

Comment: @granty Thanks for pointing out that content-security-policy.com has content gaps. I sent a pull request to fix the 'unsafe-eval' factual error on the 'strict-dynamic' page, and it looks like they're [open to more pull requests](https://github.com/foundeo/content-security-policy.com) if you remember any other errors.